# Was the First Extragalactic Planet discovered in Andromeda Galaxy

Tags: exoplanet

In the news today, they announce a first possible planet outside the Milky Way galaxy has been spotted, in the Whirpool Galaxy.  https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-59044650

Surely the first planet to be possibly be discovered was in 2009 . https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17287-first-extragalactic-exoplanet-may-have-been-found/

The Question is, was the Andromeda planet later discounted for the Whirlpool planet to become the first or bad reporting.

Comment: You are linking to the wrong article.  You want https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17287-first-extragalactic-exoplanet-may-have-been-found/

Comment: New Scientists wouldn't let me view the correct article so i linked the article which i could view with just the one line mentioning Andromeda's planet.  To avoid confusion, I've linked to the more appropriate article.

Answer (score 1):

The *New Scientist* article mentions that the star is “an interloper from another galaxy” and that it is “2300 light years from Earth.” This places it well *inside* the Milky Way.

So, the star and its planet[s?] were probably *made* in another galaxy, but they *are* not in another galaxy now.

Today’s announcement does remain true.

Comment: As James points out, I linked the wrong article, the article I linked only has one line mentioning Andromeda's planet.