# Is one transit enough to be confident that we detected an exoplanet

Tags: observational-astronomy, exoplanet, planetary-transits

Everything is pretty much in the title. I was thinking about the transit method and was wondering if the signature of a transit on the light curve of a star is distinctive enough to only need one transit for confirmation. I know that to deduce other information like the period or the distance of the planet you need more transit, but is one enough to confirm the presence of an exoplanet ?

Is there other phenomena that can produce this type of light curve ? For example if a cloud of gas would pass in front of the star i would expect the brightness to drop for a long time. I would expect also the probability of a small solid objects passing in front of the star far away such that it's angular size would be the same as of a planet would be very rare.

Or maybe is it because our measurement is too noisy and we need to correlate a signal over time to be confident that we observed a transit ?

Comment: There are other false-positive signals that produce transits - e.g. unresolved background eclipsing binaries, grazing incidence eclipses and others.

Comment: related: [After only one eclipse of its X-ray bright primary, how can astronomers estimate the first extragalactic exoplanet's period to be about 70 years?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47224/7982)

Comment: [Kepler and the Transiting Exoplanet Survey Satellite (TESS) requires at least two transits -- that is, two equal dips in brightness from the same star to detect exoplanets.](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/1524/how-do-you-find-and-confirm-a-planet-10-things-about-the-search-for-exoplanets/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is one transit enough to be confident that we detected an exoplanet?

I will argue:

#### No.

and back it up with material contained in my earlier question [After only one eclipse of its X-ray bright primary, how can astronomers estimate the first extragalactic exoplanet's period to be about 70 years?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47224/7982)

> Phys.org's [Astronomers may have discovered the first planet outside of our galaxy](https://phys.org/news/2021-10-astronomers-planet-galaxy.html) links to Di Stefano et al. 2021 [A ***possible*** planet candidate in an external galaxy detected through X-ray transit](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-021-01495-w) (earlier [arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08987)) and says:
>
> > **While this is a tantalizing study, more data would be needed to verify the interpretation as an extragalactic exoplanet.** One challenge is that the planet candidate's large orbit means it would not cross in front of its binary partner again for about 70 years, **thwarting any attempts for a confirming observation for decades.**
> >
> > "Unfortunately to confirm that we're seeing a planet we would likely have to wait decades to see another transit," said co-author Nia Imara of the University of California at Santa Cruz. "And because of the uncertainties about how long it takes to orbit, we wouldn't know exactly when to look."
> >
> > Can the dimming have been caused by a cloud of gas and dust passing in front of the X-ray source? The researchers consider this to be an unlikely explanation, as the characteristics of the event observed in M51-ULS-1 are not consistent with the passage of such a cloud. The model of a planet candidate is, however, consistent with the data.

See the excellent answers there to get a better idea of the great extent to which the authors have build a scientific case for "exoplanetship" without actually calling it an exoplanet.

Unless otherwise stated, orbits of planets (exos or in our own system) are pretty much *periodic* and I think that closed, well-defined and roughly periodic orbits are part of the definition of what a planet is, even if it's not explicitly stated as such.

How do we know if a transit is from an orbiting body?

As you point out transit *periodicity* is a hallmark of an exoplanet identification using the transit method (as it is for spectroscopic methods) and without a few repeats you don't have periodicity.

Accretion material, starspots, and unkown/unidentified intervening bodies are just some of the ways that a single dip might happen.

So even with all the circumstantial evidence cited within Di Stefano et al. 2021, the authors are careful to make clear the difference between a dip *consistent with* that of an exoplanet, and a likely exoplanet or confirmed exoplanet.