# It is possible to estimate an exoplanets' orbital period from just one transit?

Tags: mathematics, transits-other-than-sun

Is one lightcurve containing a dip in brightness obtained from the transit method sufficient to obtain or estimate the orbital period of an exoplanet - such that one (first) observation could be used to reliably schedule a second observation for confirmation in advance?

Comment: No. You don’t know the size of the object, its (absolute) speed (as opposed to angular), its distance, etc. You don’t even know *if* the object will pass again in front of the star!

Comment: @PierrePaquette [After only one eclipse of its X-ray bright primary, how can astronomers estimate the first extragalactic exoplanet's period to be about 70 years?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47224/7982)

Comment: @uhoh They make a good case there, but astronomers might not have all such relevant information about the observed event and its associated star…

Comment: Oh! and this is why I commented instead of answered… ;-)

Comment: @PierrePaquette it's a proof of concept but this question needs a complete answer based on different cases (as you have pointed out it depends a lot on the information available to try to model the primary) which I'm not really up to.

Comment: Me neither… Sorry!

Comment: Probably first we would need to know the distance from the star via redshift, then during the transit occulation, we could estimate the distance between the star and the planet, then using spectroscopy we could measure the radial velocity and then input it into Kepler's 3rd law